# Windows 8.1 - Show Status Bar

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer

The status bar is not showing in Windows Explorer. I have ticked Folder Options, View, Show Status Bar. I have also tried restarting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check the registry key of the "Status Bar": The key is available under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\ShowStatusBar
```

It is a 'DWORD' key and 0 = Off and 1 = On

So please check this value. If the value is not present then add the value and restart the machine and check your results.